# How to pass and access list of complex objects and its properties to freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

The Java model that is passed to freemarker template:

```
public clazz {
public void methodOne() {
        List<InvoiceObject> invoices = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> properties = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                    .put("invoiceNumber", invoiceNumber)
                    .build();
invoices.add(InvoiceObject.builder().properties(properties).build());
// adding model as atribbute and invoiking process method
 }
    @Data
    @Builder
    public static class InvoiceObject { // inner class
        public Map<String, String> properties;
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<#list invoices as invoice>
    <tr>
        <td>${invoice.properties["invoiceNumberBuy"]}<td>
    </#list>
```

It results in:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing
```

**UPDATE:**

The template had to have `invoiceNumber` instead of `invoiceNumberBuy`. 
**${invoice.properties.invoiceNumber}**

Comment: You have to iterate the Map.

Comment: You haven't pasted the part of the error message that tells what's missing. Also in the Java code you have `invoiceNumber`, while in the template you have `invoiceNumberBuy`.

Comment: BTW, `invoice.properties["invoiceNumberBuy"]` can be written as `invoice.properties.invoiceNumberBuy`. Does the same but nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Map Iteration is Wrong . Probably You should try like below.

```
<#list invoices as invoice>
    <tr>
<#list invoice.properties?keys as prop>
        <td>${invoice.properties['${prop}']}<td>
</#list>
</tr>
  </#list>
```

Comment: OP didn't say that he needs to discover the properties dynamically, so he doesn't need to list it. But if he has to list them, then your example can be simplified. As you only use the property values, you should just directly list `invoice.properties?values`. If you need the key too, then you should use `<#list invoice.properties as k, v>${k} = ${v}</#list>` syntax. Also, things like `invoice.properties['${prop}']` should be written as `invoice.properties[prop]`.